# setPropertiesToFetch: and setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO with relationships

Tags: core-data, relationships, fault

The problem is that even by using setPropertiesToFetch: and setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO setting a relationship will cause 2 additional "select ..." on my sqlite3 database.

I have a task and a job model with a relationship between them. Task has one job and a job_id and job has one task. Im importing a lot of tasks and jobs. To speed up the process i import all tasks and jobs first before setting the relationship. The import works fine. When i set the relationship something unexpectedly happen. I use the following code to set the relationships.

```
int limit = 100;
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate newMoc];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"job = nil"]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:limit];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"job", @"job_id", nil]];
[fetchRequest setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:NO];
[fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:NO];

while (true) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *tasks = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];           
        if (!error) {
            if (tasks.count > 0) {

                NSMutableSet *jobIDs = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];                 
                for (Task *task in tasks) {                     
                    [jobIDs addObject:task.job_id];
                }                   

                NSArray *jobs = [ListObjectsManager objectsForIDs:jobIDs properties:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"baseObjectID", @"task", nil] entityName:JobClassName moc:moc];
                [jobIDs release];
                for (Task *task in tasks) {

                    for (Job *job in jobs) {

                        if (task.job_id.intValue == job.baseObjectID.intValue) {
                            task.job = job;
                            job.task = task;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                [appDelegate saveContext:moc];
            }
            else {
                //No more relationships to set
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR FETCHING : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
}

[fetchRequest release];
```

the line **task.job = job** creates 2 new "select ..."!?!

This produce a lot of selects which i'd like to avoid.

---

**Addition**

```
NSArray *tasks = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

creates "**SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZJOB, t0.ZJOB_ID FROM ZTASK t0 WHERE   t0.ZJOB IS NULL  LIMIT 100**" which works as expected.

```
NSLog(@"%d", [tasks objectAtIndex:0].job_id.intValue);
```

creates no new "Select..." which works as expected.

```
[tasks objectAtIndex:0].job_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:63];
```

creates:

2013-05-10 00:26:59.048[1197:1803] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBASEOBJECTID, t0.ZBASEOBJECTNAME, t0.ZJOB_DESCRIPTION, t0.ZJOB_ID, t0.ZJOB FROM ZTASK t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
2013-05-10 00:26:59.058[1197:1803] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0099s
2013-05-10 00:26:59.061[1197:1803] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0133s for 1 rows.
2013-05-10 00:26:59.064[1197:1803] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x1f540670

Why does it fault fulfilled when a property is set and how can i avoid that?

Thanks in advanced!